# When I write a sentence " Around 90% of population are Hinduism"

Tags: grammar

In the above sentence, Is it correct grammatically ? When I write it is said its wrong.
Where is the wrong

Comment: You may find this useful https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/273585/does-a-percentage-quantity-take-singular-or-plural-verb-agreement

Comment: None of the population are Hunduism. Some of them may be Hindu, and therefore practice (or espouse) Hinduism.

Answer (score 1):

Hinduism is the name of the religion.  A person is not a religion.

You don't say "He is a Hinduism".

You do say "Hinduism is common in India".

You do say "He believes in Hinduism".

A person who believes in Hinduism is called a Hindu.

You do say "He is a Hindu."

You do say "Around 90% of the population are Hindus".